# Xcode6 Swift / Obj-C "library not found"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods

So I've read all the relevant threads on SO regarding this specific error, but I still cannot find a solution. The project I just downloaded was written in Obj-C (recently), and I keep getting a "ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" error... this project uses Cocoapods, and I've already done "pod install" to update all the pods. It should also be noted that this project has two targets in the build, and I'm only getting an error for one of the targets. Is it possible that Cocoapods only installed for one of the two targets? If so, how should I install for both targets?

Comment: You and try to download direct AFNetworking Github and install it on your project manually?